# Decoding SquareUp Card Reader Audio

Tags: iphone, audio, decode

SquareUp.com offers a free hardware device to those that register for their service. This device reads magnetic card stripes and sends audio though the headphone/mic jack to the application.

Has anyone been able to figure out how to access and decode the audio from this device in their own apps?

Comment: I hope it isn't too easy, otherwise people will start writing lookalikes that steal card details, or re-play the audio to fake transactions.

Comment: @Phil See the discussion around VeriFone's mudslinging against Square: http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2011/03/09/dont-believe-the-fud-square-is-only-as-insecure-as-you-let-it-be/ .  You are at risk any time you hand someone your card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there have been no real answers, I'm going to assume nobody has figured this out and the answer, for now at least, is that it cannot be done.